# Подключение dadata во Vue

Tags: vue.js

Хочу воспользоваться [vue-компонентом](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-suggestions) для плагина сервиса подсказок DaData. 
Создал компонент как и указано в `Readme`.

**VueSuggestions.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <VueSuggestions
        :model.sync="city"
        :coordinates.sync="coordinates"
        :placeholder="'Начните вводить'"
        :class="form-control"
        :options="suggestionOptions">
    </VueSuggestions>
  </div>
</template>

  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        city: '',
        coordinates: {
          latitude: '',
          longitude: ''
        },
        suggestionOptions: {
          token: 'b4390c81d1a08f730d018daf7d62ca6b08376ec2',
          type: "ADDRESS",
          scrollOnFocus: false,
          triggerSelectOnBlur: false,
          triggerSelectOnEnter: false,
          addon: 'none',
          onSelect (suggestion) {

          }
        },
      }
    },
    components: { VueSuggestions }
  }
```

В результате получаю:

```
Property or method "form" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render
```

В чем может быть ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В строке **:class="form-control"** уберите двоеточие в начале